# Adding a BitmapImage to a Canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to load a BitmapImage from an embedded source image and add this to a UIComponent.  I am attaching the code that I have below.  I have not been able to get this to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var bitmap:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.source ="@Embed('sample.jpg')";
var graphic:Graphic = new Graphic();
graphic.addElement(bitmap);
thumbHolder.addChild(graphic);
```

When I run this I dont get an error, but no image appears in thumbHolder (My UIComponent).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding when using ActionScript works a bit differently than in MXML.  In this case, you are setting the source to a string (and not an embedded image).

```
// Defined somewhere else in your class
[Embed(source="sample.jpg")]
public var embeddedImage:Class;

// Setting the source the right way
var bitmap:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.source = embeddedImage;
var graphic:Graphic = new Graphic();
graphic.addElement(bitmap);
thumbHolder.addChild(graphic);
```

Comment: Thanks alot    Im gona try this in a bit